# One IMP_PORT connected to multiple EXPORTS

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am creating a scoreboard which has a single implication port. I want to connect multiple exports from a parent class to the same imp port of the scoreboard class I am writing. Essentially (in pseudo-code):

```
class parent_class extends uvm_scoreboard;

  uvm_analysis_export #(my_type) export0;
  uvm_analysis_export #(my_type) export1;
  uvm_analysis_export #(my_type) export2;
  uvm_analysis_export #(my_type) export3;

  my_scoreboard m_scb;

  function void connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    export0.connect(m_scb.my_imp);
    export1.connect(m_scb.my_imp);
    export2.connect(m_scb.my_imp);
    export3.connect(m_scb.my_imp);

  endfunction
endclass

class my_scoreboard extends uvm_scoreboard;

  uvm_analysis_imp#(my_type) my_imp;

  function void write (my_type);
    // do something here
  endfunction

endclass
```

This works fine but I am wondering now, if we get 2 or 3 or 4 transactions broadcasted from their ports on the same clock cycle, will the `write` function be called twice/thrice/4times? This is the behaviour I would want.

I don't have a dependency on the order in which they are called but don't want to miss a broadcast because of my setup.

Comment: Don't you mean 'implementation port'?

Comment: @ArunD'souza: Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple `write()`s called in an indeterminate order. If the scoreboard needs to know which port it came from, you will have to put that information in the transaction.